# Google+ span element disappears while signing in

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I have this code

```
<span
                    id="signinButton"
                    class="g-signin"
                    data-callback="signinCallback"
                    data-clientid="383980626115-6g1kc77ltl2edrh4dopdmfasu0r7j7dn.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
                    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
                    data-width="wide"
                    data-height="standard"
                    style="display:none;"
                    >

</span>
```

I want to remove this button when signing in, so I am doing this on sign in:-

```
if (AuthStates.google['access_token']) {
  // Signed in with Google, you can now use Google+ APIs.
  console.log(AuthStates.google);

  document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
      'userId': 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      document.getElementById('cname').value =resp.displayName;
      document.getElementById('cemail').value =resp.emails[0].value;
      console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName + ' ' + resp.emails[0].value);
    });
  });
}
```

but it throws error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null google+ signin`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span
                    id="signinButton"
                    class="g-signin"
                    data-callback="signinCallback"
                    data-clientid="383980626115-6g1kc77ltl2edrh4dopdmfasu0r7j7dn.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
                    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
                    data-width="wide"
                    data-height="standard"

</span>
```

For style editing you shouldn't use setAttribute

```
if (AuthStates.google['access_token']) {
  // Signed in with Google, you can now use Google+ APIs.
  console.log(AuthStates.google);

  document.getElementById('signinButton').style.display= 'none';

  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
      'userId': 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      document.getElementById('cname').value =resp.displayName;
      document.getElementById('cemail').value =resp.emails[0].value;
      console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName + ' ' + resp.emails[0].value);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve my problem some other way. But this suggestion was helpful as well ! So implemented!